# Error: can not cal method 'addCls' of null {ExtJs4}

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I'm using [Bryntum charts](http://bryntum.com)and [extjs4](http://www.sencha.com) for my project.
This is the error I am getting since yesterday[image: Snap from debug console of chrome]

I understand that the method addCls is not defined.

How to tackle this error.

My code file is very big somewhere around 1500 lines, But if it is required for the understanding of question then i will paste the whole code too....

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a breakpoint on the line that throws an exception. Figure out which object (culprit) is trying to call addCls() method and then edit the breakpoint to add a condition like this:

culprit == undefined

next time code will halt just before you hit your bug. you can then inspect the stack and see the call hierarchy to this point.

Comment: I'm getting above error in chrome and "Ext.fly(b) is null" error in firefox. both are causing the same problem...

Comment: Sir, I tried debugging the way you told me, it breaks on ext-all.js file at line 15.The problem is the whole code is at line 15 only.....Its a huge line and i can't figure out the bug...........And the code works perfectly in IE6...I have no clue why...:(

Comment: You need to use ext-debug version of the library.

Comment: I've figured out the problem......Your answer did helped me.....Thnaks for your kind support...:)